# inside while loop data not displaying in php

Tags: php

Hi in the below i want to show Consultation Charges values for that i took the td.But in that td not displying anything even td also not showing.

After executing this query i want to find the no. of rows based on the rows i want to display the data.

My expected output:

Bill Particular Bill Sub Particular Doctor Date Dis. Amt.

Consultation Charges:

all the values based on no of rows.

**php**

```
<table width="100%">
            <th>Bill Particular</th>
            <th>Bill Sub Particular</th>
            <th>Doctor</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Dis. Amt.</th>
            <th>Charge</th>
            <th>No. of Times</th>
            <th>Amount</th>

        </table>
<tr><th colspan=2>Consultation Charges:</th>

            <?php
            $div_options = array();
                $sql = "SELECT ibp.ipd_bp_id, ibp.bp_id, bp.bp_name, ibp.bsp_id, bsp.bsp_name, ibp.doctor_id, ab.employee_name doctor, ibp.date date, ibp.amount charge, ibp.discount_amount discount, ibp.no_of_time, (ibp.no_of_time * ibp.amount) total_amount
FROM bill_particular_master bp
INNER JOIN ipd_bill_particular ibp ON ibp.bp_id = bp.bp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bill_sub_particular bsp ON bsp.bsp_id = ibp.bsp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN address_book ab ON ab.employee_id = ibp.doctor_id
WHERE ibp.ipd_reg_no =  '$ipd_no'
AND bsp.consultant =1
AND bsp.package = 0
AND bsp.admission = 0
AND bp.bp_name != 'Scan Charges' 
AND bp.bp_name !='Procedure'";

            $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
            //$row=$dbh->fetch();
            $i=1;
            while($row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $sub_arr['bp_name'] = $row['bp_name'];  
            $sub_arr['bsp_name'] = $row['bsp_name'];
            echo "<tr>
            <td>Here is the text - " . $sub_arr['bp_name'] . "</td> 
            <td>The ID of the text is - " .$sub_arr['bsp_name'] . "</td>";
            if($i !== 0) { 
            echo "<td>The ID of the previous entry is - " .$sub_arr['bp_name'] . "</td>";
            } 
            else { 
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            } 
            echo "</tr>"; 

            $i = $row['bp_name']; 
            }
            ?>


        </tr>
```

Comment: is your query ($row) returning the results???

Comment: it's giving this error Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()

Comment: I think your $i is type of int and as you comparing with identity and it is initially it is assigned to 1. so the statement if ($i !== 0 ) will fail and it will execute the else part that is '<td>&nbsp;<td>'.

On next iteration you are assigning $i with the value of $row['bp_name'] and that might be a type of string. So here also your if condition will fail.As your $row['bp_name']  will not have a value of 0.

Comment: how to get the correct solution because tr also i want to iterate

Comment: From your "call to undefined method PDO::fetch" it sounds like there's a bug in `$dbh->query()`. Without knowing what `$dbh` is it'll be impossible to debug. It should return a `PDOStatement` but returns an `PDO` object? Print out `$sth` (`var_dump($sth)`) and check. Also tell us how you create `$dbh`. (do **not** post any credentials/information about your DB!) Please also be aware that you have an SQL injection error (`$ipd_no`) and should bind the parameter instead. Google has millions of tutorials explaining this. Simply search for "bind pdo".

Comment: @h2ooooooo Now there is no error but nothing was printing

Comment: @hspcare Are you sure that your query actually receives any data? Have you tried printing out your query and running it directly on your database through another piece of software?

Comment: @h2ooooooo another page i used

Comment: @hspcare You didn't answer any of my questions? Have you tried the query? Does it return something in another query browser (PHPMyAdmin / HeidiSQL / SequelPro / Mysql Workbench / etc. etc. etc)

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes my query executing correct

Comment: Right after you've executed your query, try to dump it `var_dump($sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`. Try *some* debugging yourself. If you staticly type in your `$ipd_no` or bind it, does it work then?

Comment: where i want to add that code

Comment: Right after you've executed your query. Right after `$sth = $dbh->query($sql);`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo bool(false) giving this result

Comment: Then you would've gotten another error. Anyway, if you read the documentation you can see that this means that the query did not execute, and therefore is wrong, so you didn't print it out and type it into your query browser like I asked. You can check your error (once again, Google "pdo check error"). Please correct your query. If you're not looking to do anything yourself, I'm sure [a freelancer would love to help you out for a price](http://www.freelancer.com).

Comment: @hspcare Then please post an answer so someone else can figure it out in case they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>The ID of the previous entry is - " . $row['bp_name'] . "</td>";
```

You have there variable thats not even defined in your code.

Comment: how is your $dbh set up? since you are using PDO it should be something like this: $dbh = new PDO(correct things in here)

Comment: if your $dbh is correctly set up try this uncomment the line $rows = $dbh-fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

and use foreach ($rows as $row) instead of while

Comment: can you show your $dbh variable? remove user/password/domain before you paste it here